# Is there a closed form expression for the number of $k$-words in an $n$-alphabet with each letter appearing an even number of times?

Tags: combinatorics

This may be a very well known question in combinatorics that I am not able to figure out quickly:

Suppose that $S$ is the set of all $k$-tuples $(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k) \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}^k$ such that each of the entries $i_1,\ldots,i_k$ appear an even number of times. For example, if $n=5$ and $k=4$, $(1,1,2,2), (1,2,1,2)$ and $(3,3,3,3)$ are some of the elements of $S$. **Is there a closed form expression for the cardinality of $S$?** Of course $|S| = 0$ if $k$ is odd, but what for even $k$?

I tried to run a recursion along $n$, but cannot quite get it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not aware of a closed form, but if you fix $n$, then you find its exponential generating function is $\cosh(x)^n,$ from which you can eventually find, for even $k$, that
$$|S| = 2^{1-n} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}(n-2j)^k\binom{n}{j}$$

Comment: Thanks @Brian Moehring!